# Rails 4 Sanitizing User Input

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, json, sanitize

I am currently making an API using Ruby on Rails. I was just wondering in general if there are built in Rails methods or libraries/gems to sanitize Json and SQL or if Rails 4 does this by default? I am most worried about such cases where I have an SQL statement such as

```
User.where("users.first_name IS NOT NULL")
```

or something like

```
Event.where(:location => params[:location]).
```

Essentially, what should I watch out for in my SQL syntax and in incoming JSON requests?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Rails will do it automatically if you format your queries properly

From the [guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection)  - don't do things like:

```
Project.where("name = '#{params[:name]}'")
```

Instead do

```
Project.where("name = ?", params[:name])
```

Comment: Good point about the question mark for interpolation, but I'm not clear on if  `Event.where(:location => params[:location]).` would get sanitized.

Comment: @maxpleaner it would do - [further down the guides page](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection-countermeasures)

Answer (score 13):

By default, using the following will sanitize the `str` and make it **safe from SQL injections**:

```
User.where(name: str)
User.where('name ILIKE ?', str)
```

However, the following code (direct string interpolation then given to the `where` method) make it **unsafe from SQL injections**:

```
User.where("name = '#{str}'")
```

---

**In your case**, you can use `ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize(your_string_from_user_input)`. It will use your DB adapter to escape/quote the relevant parts, **preventing from SQL injections**.

In a Model, you can directly access to the `sanitize` method (since you are in a context already inheriting from ActiveRecord::Base):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.search(string)
    terms = string.split
    searchable_columns = [:name, :username, :whatever]
    query = terms.map do |term|
      fields = searchable_columns.map |column|
        " #{self.table_name}.#{column} LIKE '#{sanitize("%#{term}%")}'"
      end
      "(#{fields.join(' OR ')})"
    end.join(' AND ')

    where(query)
  end
end
```

The above code will produce a SQL WHERE clause like the following:

```
# str is 'bob doe'
WHERE 
  (users.name LIKE 'bob' OR users.username LIKE 'bob' OR users.whatever LIKE 'bob')
AND
  (users.name LIKE 'doe' OR users.username LIKE 'doe' OR users.whatever LIKE 'doe')
```

Comment: That's a nice solution.